# Python - How to stop code from continuing

Tags: python

I have a function that enables and disables services from the `Netscaler`. I pass in either `enable` or `disable`.

However, I want it to exit in the event someone passes a different value. I tried `break`ing out of it but it tells me my `break` is outside the loop. How can I resolve this?

```
def servicegroup_action(servicegroup_name,action):
    if not action.upper() in ('ENABLE','DISABLE'):
        break

    try:
        # do stuff
    except NSNitroError, e:
        print e.message
```

Comment: You're in a function. Maybe you mean `return`?

Comment: Yep, `return` works. Thanks, had a brain fart for a minute there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `return` so as to terminate the function execution; a `break` is used to break out of a loop, and within your current code, there is no associated `for`/`while` loop.

The other option is to execute your code only if the correct values are passed, by indenting the `try`-`except` within the `if` block:

```
def servicegroup_action(servicegroup_name,action):
    if action.upper() in ('ENABLE','DISABLE'):
        try:
            # do stuff
        except NSNitroError, e:
            print e.message
```

Comment: im such an idiot. LOL. Thanks I'm good now. I've been coding in PHP all day and had to switch to Python for a "quick" job.

Comment: ...better than my answer (deleted). Certainly more pythonic. :-D